# Copy list item behaves inconsistently

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I've got a SharePoint 2010 workflow that has one step, "Copy list item". This workflow gets kicked of when an item is created in the source list, and copies the current item to the target list.

Every time an item is entered into the source, the workflow kicks off. However, sometimes, it only creates a blank row in the target instead of copying all the data. So far, this behavior happens intermittently and I have not been able to find a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, try adding pause(maybe for few seconds) to your workflow to let SharePoint complete creation of item in first list.